# eclipse: can't finish GWT installation

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, plugins

(Eclipse Juno 4.2)

I'm using the wizard, that appears when you try to create a GWT User Interface. The first time I ran it, eclipse froze halfway, and I had to kill the process.

Now I get to this point:

[screenshot](http://s14.directupload.net/images/130321/ndpzvrqj.jpg).

The thing is: neither the Next nor the Finish button is clickable. Just nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the wizard in your screenshot is the install wizard. I recently installed GWT and it worked OK. Make sure that you're installing from the 4.2 repository here: http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.2. It might be better to install this separately without being prompted by the user interface wizard. Install GWT by clicking on Help -> Install New Software... -> Add, then add the repository above.

When I installed GWT, I ticked the following:

- Google Plugins for Eclipse
- GWT Designs for GPE
- SDKs

... and it all should install OK under Juno 4.2